# How to retrieving & display data from multiple tables under the same heading?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am making an Employee Roster Scheduler.
Currently, I'm trying to use a repeater to display the current shifts in a calendar format.
Below is my current output:
[image: snip1]
As you can see, there are 2 shifts on Saturday. Does anyone know how I can place these two shifts under one header, so Saturday 03 June 2017 only appears once, rather than twice?

Below you can find my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
                <asp:Repeater ID="repSubscription" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repSubscription_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div class="col-lg-2">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color: #3A6EA5; color: white">
                                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                                        <%# Eval("Start_Time", "{0:dddd, dd MMMM yyyy}") %>
                                    </h4>
                                </div>
                                <!--panel-heading-->
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="repShift" runat="server">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <b><%# Eval("Job_Title") %></b>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                    </br>
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="repEmp" runat="server">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# Eval("Employee_Name") %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                    <br />
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="repTimes" runat="server">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <%# Eval("Start_Time", "{00:HH:MM}") %> - <%# Eval("End_Time" , "{00:HH:MM}") %>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </div>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.bindRepeater();
}

private void bindRepeater()
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
        comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Start_Date, End_Date FROM My_Subscription WHERE Subscription_Id = 1", conn);
        SqlDataReader reader1 = comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader1.Read())
        {
            startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader1["Start_Date"]);
            endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(reader1["End_Date"]);

            //lblError.Text += startDate.ToString() + "<br/>" + endDate.ToString();

        }
    conn.Close();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT Start_Time, Emp_ID, Job_ID, Emp_Sch_Id FROM My_Employee_Schedule WHERE Start_Time BETWEEN @startReportDate AND @endReportDate", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startReportDate", startDate);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endReportDate", endDate);
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    repSubscription.DataSource = dt;
                    repSubscription.DataBind();
                }
            }
    }
}

protected void repSubscription_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater repBusiness = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("repShift"));
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Job_Title FROM My_Job_Type WHERE Job_Type_Id=@Job_Type_Id");
        string Group_Id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Job_ID").ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job_Type_Id", Group_Id);
        //Need to assign the Data in datatable
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        repBusiness.DataSource = dt;
        repBusiness.DataBind();
    }
    conn.Close();


    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater repTimes = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("repTimes"));

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Start_Time, End_Time FROM My_Employee_Schedule WHERE Emp_Sch_Id=@EmpSchId");
        string Group_Id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Emp_Sch_Id").ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpSchId", Group_Id);
        //Need to assign the Data in datatable
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        repTimes.DataSource = dt;
        repTimes.DataBind();
    }


    conn.Open();
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Repeater repEmp = (Repeater)(e.Item.FindControl("repEmp"));

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Employee_Name FROM My_Employee WHERE Employee_Id=@EmpId");
        string Group_Id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Emp_ID").ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpId", Group_Id);
        //Need to assign the Data in datatable
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        repEmp.DataSource = dt;
        repEmp.DataBind();
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

, then I am happy to post it.
Thanks a lot for any help in advance!

Comment: You need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries before bobby tables comes to visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: @SeanLange Hi, hopefully they're OK now!

Comment: The queries are less scary for sure. As for the question at hand, I am not all that clear on what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SeanLange I want all existing shifts to display under the _day_ on which they will occur. But, if there are multiple shifts on one day, like above, I don't want the _day_ to be duplicated. Instead, I want those shifts to appear under the _day_ once